# Mixitup smoother content

Tags: javascript, jquery, mixitup

I use mixitup for filterable [Portfolio](https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/)

Here is demo preview - [link](http://codepen.io/testerius/full/XmXXMO)

Here is mixitup options:

```
$(function() {
  // Instantiate MixItUp:
  $('#portfolio-container').mixItUp({
    animation: {
      animateResizeContainer: true,
      duration: 1000
    }
  });
});
```

Well, I'd like to make content **move smoother**. When there are less images, everything under #portfolio-container are pushed to top so instant without smooth animation.

So my question is: how to make it more smoother?

Here is an [example](http://themes.semicolonweb.com/html/canvas/portfolio.php),  footer are pushed smooth to top when there are less images in grid.

Comment: I see no problem in the link you provided

Comment: Nevermind, it works for my project.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It works in normal project, probably in codepen it is broken.